# PTP fails to connect to debugger

Tags: eclipse, debugging, parallel-processing, gdb, mpi

I am writing this email to ask for help in setting up a debugging environment for openMPI-based applications. Currently, I am struggling with a problem that is hampering me from continuing the work. The problem is very similar to what has been posted on the stackoverflow (See: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21742148/eclipse-ptp-hangs-starting-debug-session-of-an-openmpi-application)). Its symptom is that the debugging process hangs and the parallel debugging perspective shows a “Operation in progress…” message. It is caused by an error, namely “Cannot connect to debugger”. Meanwhile, an error message “getaddrinfo: Undefined error: 0” also appear in the debugging console.

I did some search on the internet and I found an instruction for trouble shooting (See: [Link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/7/72/PTPUserDev2012_Debugger.pdf)). I already verified that:

- Launch script could work: non-debug launch works fine
- Correct number of “sdm” processes
- Routing file can be created

But I could not find one “sdm” process with argument “—master”.

Currently, I use the following software components with indicated versions:

- Parallel Tools Platform including PTP Parallel Language Development Tools, etc. (9.0.1.201509091505)
- ptp-sdm-9.0.0 (org.eclipse.ptp.macosx_9.0.0.201506101404)
- GNU gdb (7.10)

The OS I am using is OS X Yosemite (10.10.5). And I run application on the local machine.

Did anyone encounter the similar problem and happen to know how to fix it? I would appreciate any hint or help from you.

Comment: Related... https://superuser.com/questions/1450955/eclipse-ptp-parallel-debugging

Answer (score 1):

I've got the similar problem under Ubuntu 16.04.2, but just “Cannot connect to debugger”. My solution is to run Eclipse with superuser privileges, i.e. sudo ./eclipse. Hope it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that might be the cause. I ran Eclipse from a shell terminal so that I could see more text/log output. Then under **Eclipse -> Preference -> Parallel Tools -> Parallel Language Development Tools** I enabled the **Show output from commands**, and this is what I see in the parent shell (not within Eclipse):

```
Cleanup: rm -f routing_file
submit-interactive-debug: ac5df46b-c4f2-438a-9565-9b26818e880d: perl /Users/<username>/.eclipsesettings/rms/MPICH2/start_debug_job.pl mpiexec -np 4 /Users/<username>/.eclipsesettings/sdm --port=51347 --host=localhost --debugger=gdb-mi
SDM Master: /Users/<username>/.eclipsesettings/sdm -master --port=51347 --host=localhost --debugger=gdb-mi
SDM Master: sdm [--debugger=value] [--debugger_path=path]
SDM Master:     [--proxy=proxy]
SDM Master:     [--host=host_name] [--port=port]
SDM Master:      [--master]
SDM Master:     [--server=rank]
SDM Master:     [--generate_routes=list]
SDM Master:     [--routing_file=path]
SDM Master:     [--debug[=level]]
```

This suggests that one of the argument inputs to `sdm` is invalid, and indeed I see that it is receiving `-master` instead of `--master` flag.

I tried to open the perl script at `/Users/<username>/.eclipsesettings/rms/MPICH2/start_debug_job.pl` but it's correct there, and any changes made only appear within Eclipse's output console, not the parent shell I ran eclipse from. Somewhere `sdm` is being sent the wrong `-master` flag, and maybe that is part of the problem. Unfortunately I don't have an answer beyond that.

Update: I have submitted a bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=521975